# Pandas: Get count of column values and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df
   id grp1 grp2
0   1    a  NaN
1   2    b    d
```

I need to create a new column with count of values from grp1 and grp2 columns.Something like below

```
df
   id grp1 grp2 grp_count
0   1    a  NaN      1
1   2    b    d      2
```

One way of achieving this is using pandas apply with a  function to get the count iterating row by row which will affect the performance.

Is there a way we can do it without using pandas apply?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas DataFrame `count` method ignores `nan` values by default, therefore:

```
df['grp_count'] = df[['grp1', 'grp2']].count(axis=1)
```